# When Google Form is submitted, function will not work if i use multiple function calls

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script

Function will not work properly if i call other functions when form is submitted.

I have a function capturarDatos(event) that is linked to a trigger on form submit to get the responses. I load the respones to a function documentCreator, to create a doc template. When i put the code from documentCreator inside the main function, it works properly. Otherwise it will run ok, or not, randomly.
This doesn't work:

```
function capturarDatos(event) {
 var responses = event.response.getItemResponses();

 documentCreator(responses);

}




function documentCreator(responses) {
dni = responses[0].getResponse();
apellido=responses[1].getResponse();
nombre=responses[2].getResponse();
arancel=responses[3].getResponse();
anioIngreso=responses[4].getResponse();
carrera=responses[5].getResponse();
ciudadNacimiento=responses[6].getResponse();
fechaNacimiento=responses[7].getResponse();
nacionalidad=responses[8].getResponse();
domicilio=responses[9].getResponse();
localidad=responses[10].getResponse();
telefono=responses[11].getResponse();
estadoCivil=responses[12].getResponse();
codigoPostal=responses[13].getResponse();
email=responses[14].getResponse();
censo=responses[15].getResponse();
controlActas=responses[16].getResponse();
controlInterno=responses[17].getResponse();
fechaFinalizacion=responses[18].getResponse();
resolucion=responses[19].getResponse();
intervino=responses[20].getResponse();



  var templateid = "1eB3scWh_IHLTRlfjqMccN4LbZanUN_r_-oLK4zNK4_o";
    var docid = DriveApp.getFileById(templateid).makeCopy().getId();
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docid); 
    doc.setName(dni);

    var body = doc.getActiveSection();




body.replaceText("{dni}", dni);
body.replaceText("{apellido}", apellido);
body.replaceText("{nombre}", nombre);
body.replaceText("{arancel}", arancel);
body.replaceText("{anioIngreso}", anioIngreso);
body.replaceText("{carrera}", carrera);
body.replaceText("{ciudadNacimiento}", ciudadNacimiento);
body.replaceText("{fechaNacimiento}", fechaNacimiento);
body.replaceText("{nacionalidad}", nacionalidad);
body.replaceText("{domicilio}", domicilio);
body.replaceText("{localidad}", localidad);
body.replaceText("{telefono}", telefono);
body.replaceText("{estadoCivil}", estadoCivil);
body.replaceText("{codigoPostal}", codigoPostal);
body.replaceText("{email}", email);
body.replaceText("{censo}", censo);
body.replaceText("{controlActas}", controlActas);
body.replaceText("{controlInterno}", controlInterno);
body.replaceText("{fechaFinalizacion}", fechaFinalizacion);
body.replaceText("{resolucion}", resolucion);
body.replaceText("{intervino}", intervino);





        doc.saveAndClose()
        lele= doc.getId();



        var o;

  o = {
    'fileToMoveID':lele,
    "targetFolderID":"1AUYekR4pM7y7i0h5yyn94bYAc0hdeXZ2"
  }

  moveFile(o);

  }


function moveFile(parameterObject) {
  var currentFolderID,file,fileToMoveID,sourceFolder,targetFolder,targetFolderID;

  fileToMoveID = parameterObject.fileToMoveID;
  currentFolderID = parameterObject.currentFolderID;
  targetFolderID = parameterObject.targetFolderID;

  file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileToMoveID);//Get the file to move

  if (!file) {
    functionToHandleThisKindOfThing("there is no file");
    return;
  }

  if (currentFolderID) {//The folder ID holding the current file was passed in
    sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(currentFolderID);
  } else {//No ID for the current folder
    sourceFolder = file.getParents();
    if (sourceFolder) {
      if (sourceFolder.hasNext()) {
        sourceFolder = sourceFolder.next();
      }
    }
  }

  targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolderID);

  targetFolder.addFile(file);
  sourceFolder.removeFile(file);
}
```

This works:

```
function capturarDatos(event) {
 var responses = event.response.getItemResponses();


dni = responses[0].getResponse();
apellido=responses[1].getResponse();
nombre=responses[2].getResponse();
arancel=responses[3].getResponse();
anioIngreso=responses[4].getResponse();
carrera=responses[5].getResponse();
ciudadNacimiento=responses[6].getResponse();
fechaNacimiento=responses[7].getResponse();
nacionalidad=responses[8].getResponse();
domicilio=responses[9].getResponse();
localidad=responses[10].getResponse();
telefono=responses[11].getResponse();
estadoCivil=responses[12].getResponse();
codigoPostal=responses[13].getResponse();
email=responses[14].getResponse();
censo=responses[15].getResponse();
controlActas=responses[16].getResponse();
controlInterno=responses[17].getResponse();
fechaFinalizacion=responses[18].getResponse();
resolucion=responses[19].getResponse();
intervino=responses[20].getResponse();



  var templateid = "1eB3scWh_IHLTRlfjqMccN4LbZanUN_r_-oLK4zNK4_o";
    var docid = DriveApp.getFileById(templateid).makeCopy().getId();
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docid); 
    doc.setName(dni);

    var body = doc.getActiveSection();




body.replaceText("{dni}", dni);
body.replaceText("{apellido}", apellido);
body.replaceText("{nombre}", nombre);
body.replaceText("{arancel}", arancel);
body.replaceText("{anioIngreso}", anioIngreso);
body.replaceText("{carrera}", carrera);
body.replaceText("{ciudadNacimiento}", ciudadNacimiento);
body.replaceText("{fechaNacimiento}", fechaNacimiento);
body.replaceText("{nacionalidad}", nacionalidad);
body.replaceText("{domicilio}", domicilio);
body.replaceText("{localidad}", localidad);
body.replaceText("{telefono}", telefono);
body.replaceText("{estadoCivil}", estadoCivil);
body.replaceText("{codigoPostal}", codigoPostal);
body.replaceText("{email}", email);
body.replaceText("{censo}", censo);
body.replaceText("{controlActas}", controlActas);
body.replaceText("{controlInterno}", controlInterno);
body.replaceText("{fechaFinalizacion}", fechaFinalizacion);
body.replaceText("{resolucion}", resolucion);
body.replaceText("{intervino}", intervino);





        doc.saveAndClose()
        lele= doc.getId();



        var o;

  o = {
    'fileToMoveID':lele,
    "targetFolderID":"1AUYekR4pM7y7i0h5yyn94bYAc0hdeXZ2"
  }

  moveFile(o);

  }


function moveFile(parameterObject) {
  var currentFolderID,file,fileToMoveID,sourceFolder,targetFolder,targetFolderID;

  fileToMoveID = parameterObject.fileToMoveID;
  currentFolderID = parameterObject.currentFolderID;
  targetFolderID = parameterObject.targetFolderID;

  file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileToMoveID);//Get the file to move

  if (!file) {
    functionToHandleThisKindOfThing("there is no file");
    return;
  }

  if (currentFolderID) {//The folder ID holding the current file was passed in
    sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(currentFolderID);
  } else {//No ID for the current folder
    sourceFolder = file.getParents();
    if (sourceFolder) {
      if (sourceFolder.hasNext()) {
        sourceFolder = sourceFolder.next();
      }
    }
  }

  targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolderID);

  targetFolder.addFile(file);
  sourceFolder.removeFile(file);
}
```

I expected to work seamlessly using functions, but it halts randomly, i need functions to create more documents on submission. 
I tried to call a basic function with Logger.log, and responses is ok.

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. Can I ask you about the detail information of `not work properly`? 2. In your script, `documentCreator(responses)` is run in the function of `capturarDatos`. But at `function documentCreator() {}`, there is no argument. Is this due to miss-copy?

Comment: 1. It will not create any new document file, if i put the same block of code defined by documentCreator(responses), it will generate documents smoothly. I see no errors in execution triggers, but it takes a lot in seconds to load. 2. Yes miss-copy.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In my environment, I cannot replicate your issue. I apologize for this. By the way, when I saw your script, I noticed that `getActiveSection()` is used. This method was renamed to `getBody()` at [April 15, 2013](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2013#april_15_2013).

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your issue correctly. You mean that if you past the contents of `function documentCreator(responses) ` into `function capturarDatos(event)` it works, but if you call `documentCreator(responses) ` from  `function capturarDatos(event)` it does not work? It would be helpful if you could provide snippets of both the working and the not working codes.

Comment: Yes, if i put the content works. I pasted the working condition.

Comment: From your code, I cannot see why the function call wouldn't work. Have you had a look at the executions? Keep in mind that the maximum runtime time per script is 6 min. If the function sometimes runs and sometimes doe not - it might be an issue of being close to exceeding some quota limit: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Comment: Yes i thought so. But using just a block of code it takes 0.5 s, and when i call the other function 6 s

Comment: Might be related to the fact that by passing the responses you call FormApp an additional amount of times. Apps-Script `Best Practices` documentation specifies that you should avoid calls to external services (including Google Services) because they make your code slow:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices